# executeBatchMethod() runs but fails to trigger start(...) method

Tags: apex, batch, debugging

I'm debugging a batch class which auto creates a transaction record (a custom SObject).

The following is my `executeBatchMethod()` ,

```
@InvocableMethod(label='desc.' description='desc.')
 public static void executeBatchMethod() {
    if(Test.isRunningTest() || Date.Today().day()==Integer.valueOf(Label.TEST_ONE)) {
        System.debug('----execute method called'); //This debug shows up on the logs
        Database.executeBatch(new TEST_AutoCreateTransaction(1), 400);
    }    
}
```

This method is expected to trigger the `start(Database.BatchableContext bc)` method, but this is currently not happening. Following is the start method,

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    try {             
        System.debug('----start method called'); //This debug does not show up on the logs
        String query = 'select id, TEST_Amount__c from TEST_relatedTransaction__c';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        System.debug('e.getMessage(): ' + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }             
}
```

I've verified that the query returns results and the general data setup required for the batch to run is in place. I'm trying to understand why the `start(...)` method does not run.

Comment: How are you calling executeBatchMethod from your test, and have you applied Test.startTest and Test.stopTest around that invocation? Async processing is only processed when added after Test.startTest and is actually processed synchronously on Test.stopTest.

Comment: I'm not calling it from a test class. I'm running them via a flow. I run (debug) the flow manually every time I want the batch to run.

Comment: Is an exception occurring (e.g. because Label.TEST_ONE cannot be converted to an integer, or some exception from the constructor of your batch) that stops the Database.executeBatch from being correctly executed? BTW, the use of a label in this way is an anti-pattern. You should use custom metadata or custom settings for configuration.

Comment: No exceptions because of it @PhilW, Ive queried the customLabel object and made sure its value is getting resolved. I have noted your point about it being anit-pattern, will add it to my backlog to update. But right now, Im certain that is not causing the issue.

Comment: Add yourself a "unit test" to run this "debugging" procedure, rather than use of the flow, to see if it is flow logic issues or something within the Apex code. Follow the points in my first comment. You can then run this individual unit test either through the Setup UI or via your IDE.

Comment: BTW, the batch will execute in a separate transaction to the flow, so make sure you are looking at the org's debug logs (in the developer console) not just the flow debug.

Comment: So @PhilW , I wrote a quick unit test. Create data, start test, run batch, system assert that the record is created, stop test. And the test passes as expected. And yes of course, I look at the org's debug logs always.

Comment: OK. Well, for me there isn't enough info in the question to help further. So unless someone else has any ideas I can only wish you the best of luck in working it out! (I think the issue must be outside the code shared here, if the unit test functions correctly.)

Comment: Thank you @PhilW . But please let me know if I can add anymore info. Im not sure on what exactly to add. I have exception handling in all the functions, so I would see exceptions if it fails outside these two methods. But currently I see none. Adding the entire batch class (~500 lines) here isnt going to help , is it?

Comment: I can only suggest you include detail of the flow and its invocation of the invocable method...

Comment: @PhilW, Ive figured out the issue. It was a rogue if block inside the block which was not running. So the execution just went through without exceptions but was not producing the results. Once its fixed, the batch runs without an issue. Im closing this question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurred due to a logic issue in the code. There were no errors on the code in question or the execution.